# How can I tell if a phone has been developer unlocked? (WP8)

Tags: 8.0, 8.1

Is there a clear indication / status on the phone if it's developer unlocked? If so, where is it?

Answer (score 2):

With Windows Phone 8/8.1, there is no indication on the phone if it is developer unlocked or not.

The only way to tell is to use the Windows Phone Developer Registration tool which is installed with the Windows Phone SDK (as part of Visual Studio).

If you connect your phone and see the option to 'Unregister', then your device is currently developer unlocked...

[image: Windows Phone Developer Registration dialogue]

Otherwise you'll see an option to 'Register', which means the device is currently locked.